# Which JPG Optimization Method Does GTMetrix Use?

Tags: libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo, jpegoptim

I am using jpegoptim with cronjob to optimize (even with lossy) my JPG formatted images. I use the following command

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | \
 xargs -0 jpegoptim --max=90 --strip-all --preserve --totals
```

But even, when I test with GTMetrix or Google's tool, they are still marked as "lossless compressable".

I wonder how to manage that? Is there any other method or suggested lib that I could use to compress my images without lossless compression? I've read about **libjpeg-turbo** (http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/) but I don't seem to find a way to execute it upon my images.

I appreciate for any suggestion and helps!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I need this too, I use jpegoptim too.